# Append HTML if parent has child

Tags: jquery, append, children

So I have a dropdown menu and I want to append some HTML to one of the

if it has a dropdown inside it.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>No Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown Exists ** APPEND SOME HTML **
        <ul>
            <li>This</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I know I can use this code:

```
if ($('ul li').find("ul").length) {

}
```

That will let me find out if the list item has a sub ul. But, how do I then target that specific list item so I can append some HTML in to it. I can't use the following for obvious reasons:

```
if ($('nav ul li').find("ul").length) {
$(this).*appendsomehtml*    
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `$('ul li ul').append(..);`?

Comment: Nailed it. I was trying to make it too complex!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Josh:

```
$('nav ul li ul').parent().children('a').append('<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('ul li').find('ul').each(function(){
      $(this).append("Html code");
    )};
```

I think this is what you're looking for ^^